# How to create a responsive viewport for a jpg file for a user to zoom and scroll and tap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a Googlemaps-like viewport that:

- will have a sticky sidebar next to the viewport for displaying stuff like a list of things that were clicked on the image.
- is compatible with regular JPG images
- is responsive with Bootstrap 3
- a user can zoom in, pinch, flick around the image, pan the image
- a user can click on parts of the image and have an image map that can register taps and clicks and still be compatible with responsiveness and the zooming and panning of the image

Doing this with an SVG is easy but unfortunately I need to support just a regular old JPG.

Say that I've got a huge image that's 7600 x 5000. Let's not debate the size of the image. Can someone point me in the right direction to make a viewport that satisfies the above requirements?

The code below doesn't work. When I add `.img-responsive` the resultant image cannot be zoomed in when on the phone. I'm permanently in the zoomed-out state. If I don't have `.img-responsive` the image is no longer responsive...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

            <img src="/assets/images/floorplan.jpg" width="7600" height="5000" border="0" usemap="#map" class="img-responsive" />

            <map name="map">
                <!-- #$-:Image map file created by GIMP Image Map plug-in -->
                <!-- #$-:GIMP Image Map plug-in by Maurits Rijk -->
                <!-- #$-:Please do not edit lines starting with "#$" -->
                <!-- #$VERSION:2.3 -->
                <area shape="circle" coords="323,2661,19" alt="point1" href="#" />
                <area shape="circle" coords="367,2691,19" alt="point2" href="#" />
                <area shape="circle" coords="434,2680,18" alt="point3" href="#" />
                <area shape="circle" coords="6549,478,17" alt="point4" href="#" />
                <area shape="circle" coords="3907,4582,22" alt="point5" href="#" />
            </map>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.img-responsive` class only sets a `max-width: 100%` for your image so it fits your screensize (or viewport).

If you images should not rescale but fit the screen, try something like:

html:

```
<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6">
<div class="holder">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1900/1000/sports/">
<div>
</div></div></div></div>
```

css:

```
.holder {
max-width:100%;
max-height: 150px;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: auto;    
}
```

Notice also that re-scaling your images will mesh up your map's coordinates too. See also: https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps